# Como aplicar formatação no elemento pai através da classe do elemento filho com CSS ou SASS?

Tags: css, css3

Tenho a seguinte estrutura apenas para exemplo:

```
<div>
    <div class="filho">teste</div>
</div>
```

Tenho a classe `.filho` com um `position: absolute`;
Gostaria de saber se através da classe `.filho` também consigo aplicar um `position: relative;` na `div` pai usando css ou sass apenas?

sei que posso criar uma classe para a `div` pai. Mas gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de selecionar um elemento pai através de um elemento filho em css. Pesquisei e não conseguir achar nada que me ajudasse!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Não existem *parent selectors* no CSS (ainda).

Existem várias maneiras de dinamicamente selecionar o pai de um elemento, mas todas elas envolvem um pouco de JavaScript como, por exemplo, o método [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) do jQuery.

Usando SASS, você pode fazer algo usando o operador [ampersand](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand):

```
.filho{
  position: absolute;
  div &{
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

o que gera

```
.filho {
  position: absolute;
}
div .filho {
  position: relative;
}
```

Mas veja que você ainda precisa, de alguma maneira, referenciar o seletor pai, por mais genérico que ele seja. Aqui entra um pouco do conhecimento sobre cascateamento para *talvez* conseguir simular um comportamento dinâmico, mas este nunca será 100% preciso.

[Este artigo](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/) fala sobre o problema em questão, e enfatiza o fato de que, usando CSS3 puro, é impossível fazer essa seleção do elemento pai. Existem até umas propostas de um novo pseudo-elemento para a nova especificação (algo como `.teste:parent`), mas isso ainda é um sonho distante.

Comment: Muito boa explicação. Valeu! ;)

Comment: @alan, se a resposta lhe agradou, não esqueça de marca-la como correta, caso não apareça nenhuma outra que seja melhor! =)

Comment: Opa! Não conhecia essa opção! Mas agora está marcada!